# Organizational Tree Structure in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. so pardon me for this silly question.
I want to create an organizational hierarchy as shown in the attachment.
[image]

I am pulling all the necessary information from the JSon file.

My jsx file looks like this:

Please help me with two:

1. how to give image address in the json file.
2. i have successfully created root/parent card(i.e chetan lal), how can i create it's child  elements? I tried with following code but unable to create child elements.

   ```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   import Records from '../OrgDetail.json';

   export default function Chart() {
     const center = {
        top: '60px',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(246,246,246)',
        fontSize: '12px',
        width: "250px",
        height: "85px",
        border: "1px solid grey",
        borderRadius: '25px',
        margin: 'auto',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative'
    }


    const linkstyle = {
        left: '220px',
        position: 'absolute',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        color: 'darkgrey',
        color: 'darkgrey'
    }

    const imagestyle = {

        border: '2px solid grey',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        height: '80px',
        width: '80px',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '-50px',


    }

    const namestyle = {

        position: 'absolute',
        top: '30px'

    }

    const designstyle = {

        position: 'absolute',
        top: '45px'
    }

    const buttonstyle = {

        position: 'absolute',
        top: '70px',
        borderColor: 'grey'
    }

    const myFunction = (y) => {
        console.log(y);
        var x = document.getElementById(y);
        console.log(x);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    return (
        <>

            {Records && Records.map(record => {
                return (
                    <div key={record.key} className="container" style={center}>
                        <img src={record.image} style={imagestyle} alt={record.name} />
                        <a style={linkstyle} href="/" alt=""><b>...</b></a>
                        <span style={namestyle}><b>{record.name}</b></span><br></br>
                        <p style={designstyle}>{record.designation}</p>
                        <button style={buttonstyle} >{record.child.length} &darr;</button>
                    </div>
                )

            })}

            {Records.child && Records.child.map(record => {
                return (
                    <div className="display:flex" key={record.child.key} style={center}>
                        <img src={record.child.image} style={imagestyle} alt={record.name} />
                        <a style={linkstyle} href="/" alt=""><b>...</b></a>
                        <span style={namestyle}><b>{record.child.name}</b></span><br></br>
                        <p style={designstyle}>{record.child.designation}</p>
                        <button style={buttonstyle} >{record.child.child.length} &darr;</button>
                        )
                    </div>
                )


            })}

        </>
    )

   }
   ```

JSon file:

```
[{
    "key": "p1",
    "name": "Chetan Lal",
    "designation": "Managing Director",
    "image": "D:/React/RL_org/my-app/src/Images/Chetan-Lal-edit.jpg",
    "about": "This is just test",
    "child": [
        {
            "key": "c1",
            "name": "Shagufta Merchant",
            "designation": "VP-Digital Operations & HR",
            "image": "../Images/Shagufta-Merchant-edit - Copy.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test2",
            "child": [
                {
                    "key": "gc1",
                    "name": "Manjiri Nadkarni",
                    "designation": "Manager - NA Media Ops",
                    "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "key": "ggc1",
                            "name": "Anurag Bhagrav",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - Media Ops",
                            "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ggc2",
                            "name": "Janhavi Chaudhari",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - Media Ops",
                            "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ggc3",
                            "name": "Anurag Shetty",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - Media Ops",
                            "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc2",
                    "name": "Shailendra More",
                    "designation": "Manager - NA Media Ops",
                    "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "key": "ggc1",
                            "name": "AjayKumar Padhy",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - SEO & Auto",
                            "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ggc2",
                            "name": "Jignesh Shah",
                            "designation": "Asist. Manager",
                            "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc3",
                    "name": "Vaishakhi Phadke",
                    "designation": "Asst. Manager - NA Media Ops",
                    "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "key": "ggc1",
                            "name": "Hassel Rathod",
                            "designation": "Team Manger - National",
                            "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc4",
                    "name": "Mitesh More",
                    "designation": "Training Team Manager",
                    "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc5",
                    "name": "Shrutika Jadhav",
                    "designation": "Manager - HR",
                    "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc6",
                    "name": "Tejinder Ossan",
                    "designation": "Manager - Facility",
                    "image": "placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "c2",
            "name": "Bhavesh Chauhan",
            "designation": "VP-Marketing Operations & IT",
            "image": "../Images/Bhavesh-Chauhan-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test3"
        },
        {
            "key": "c3",
            "name": "Sanket Naik",
            "designation": "VP-Marketing Operations & Graphics",
            "image": "../Images/Sanket-Naik-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test4"
        },
        {
            "key": "c4",
            "name": "Ankanksha Narula",
            "designation": "Sr. Manager - Finance",
            "image": "../Images/Akansha-Narula-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test5"
        },
        {
            "key": "c5",
            "name": "Diju Kurup",
            "designation": "Manager - Marketing Operations",
            "image": "../Images/Diju-Kurup-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test6"
        },
        {
            "key": "c6",
            "name": "Arya Andrade",
            "designation": "Manager - Facility",
            "image": "../Images/Arya-Andrade-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test7"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place the images in your public/static directory and set the paths in the data accordingly:

```json
"image": "/images/placekitten.jpg",
```

2. To render the hierarchy from data you may want to use a recursive component that renders the current element and then renders itself for each child. This produces a recursive structure to whatever depth your data is.

Might looks something like this:

```
export function Node({ item }) {
  return (
    {/* render the current item's name, etc. */}
    <div className="node">
      <div class="card">
        <img src={item.image} />
        <div className="name">{item.name}</div>
        <div className="designation">{item.designation}</div>
      </div>

      {item.child?.length && (
        <div className="children">
          {item.child.map((item) => (
            {/* render the children using this same component */}
            <Node key={item.key} item={item} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a [live demo implementation on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-forest-pylzlz) using the component above with your data, producing the result in the screenshot below.

(You could of course modify it to only show the current selection or whatever. This is intended only as an example of the approach for illustrative purposes.)

[image: screenshot of code sandbox implementation]

Comment: thanks!

I have a button to display/hide the child.however, when i click the root, it displays the child but when i click on the child it hides the entire child elements. on clicking the child, it should display it's child. 
<button style={buttonstyle} onClick={myFunction}>{item?.child?.length} &darr;</button>

const myFunction = () => { 
        var x = document.getElementById("child");
        console.log(x);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

Comment: Don’t modify the DOM directly from a React app. That’s what React is for. Use state to show/hide the child nodes.

Comment: thanks, as suggested state has been created:

<button style={buttonstyle} onClick={toggleChildNodes}>{item?.child?.length} {show ? "&uarr;" : "&darr;"}</button>

   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const toggleChildNodes = () => {
      setShow(!show);
    };

but the issue is that, when i click on the second  layer child node, it enables its sub-child nodes and it is not hiding the element that are enabled by previous element.

here what meant to say: https://giphy.com/gifs/jiCoa7lcDr6lsXZDl5

Comment: I updated my codesandbox demo to allow only one child to be expanded at a time. I also cut some of the json data to reduce the amount of visual noise, but it works the same way with the full data.

Comment: thanks, ray, it works for me but there is another issue. https://giphy.com/gifs/CaR8rHNm5KFOTncuwB

I want by default only the parent node should be displayed and all of its children should be hidden after page load complete

I did with setting expanded prop to false <Node key={item.key} item={item} expanded={false} />

but when i click the parent node, it does not display it's child node. I guess its very small piece of code needed to fix it. however, i am new to react so asking a foolish question.

Comment: The top level is a special case because it doesn't have a parent to track its expansion state. I've updated the sandbox again to wrap the data in a root node, giving the top level a parent.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but having an issue with the CSS now after using your code. I have opened a new thread for this. But your code helped me to toggle the parent/child nodes. Thanks very much. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help. If you mark this as the accepted answer I get internet points.

Comment: Accepted!! Is it possible for you to look into my css issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717946/having-issue-with-the-parent-and-child-elements-in-react/75718051#75718051