# having issue with the parent and child elements in react

Tags: reactjs

my code is shared: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-haze-xw2qk3?file=/src/App.js

I am having an issue with the CSS. after clicking any of the child elements, it changes two things:

1. the newly produces div changes the alignment of its parent div
2. the newly created div doesn't fit on the page

Can you place look into this and let me know what should be done? Please note that the provided code should work on all devices.

App.JS file:

```
 import './style.css';

import data from './OrgDetail.json';
import Chart from './Components/Chart';



function App() {
 
  const root = {
    child: data
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
 
  <Chart item={root} expanded />
    
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
enter code here
```

Chart Component:

```
> import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Chart({ item, expanded, onExpandChange }) {
  const center = {
    top: "30px",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(246,246,246)",
    fontSize: "12px",
    width: "250px",
    height: "85px",
    border: "1px solid grey",
    borderRadius: "25px",
    margin: "auto",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: "relative",
    marginBottom: "40px"
  };

  const linkstyle = {
    left: "220px",
    position: "absolute",
    textDecoration: "none",
    color: "darkgrey"
  };

  const imagestyle = {
    border: "2px solid grey",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    height: "80px",
    width: "80px",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "-50px"
  };

  const namestyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "30px"
  };

  const designstyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "45px"
  };

  const buttonstyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "70px",
    borderColor: "grey"
  };

  const [expandedChild, setExpandedChild] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div className="node">
          {item.name && (
            <div key={item.key} className="container" style={center}>
              <img src={item.image} style={imagestyle} alt={item.name} />
              <a style={linkstyle} href="/" alt="">
                <b>...</b>
              </a>
              <span style={namestyle}>
                <b>{item.name}</b>
              </span>
              <br></br>
              <p style={designstyle}>{item.designation}</p>
              {onExpandChange && item.child?.length && (
                <button style={buttonstyle} onClick={onExpandChange}>
                  {item.child?.length} {expanded ? "↑" : "↓"}
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          )}

          {expanded && (
            <div
              className="children"
              style={{
                position: "relative",
                top: "30px",
                display: "flex",
                gap: "8px"
              }}
            >
              {item.child?.map((item, idx) => (
                <Chart
                  key={idx}
                  item={item}
                  onExpandChange={() => {
                    setExpandedChild(expandedChild === idx ? null : idx);
                  }}
                  expanded={expandedChild === idx}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

orgDetails.json:

```
[
{
    "key": "p1",
    "name": "Chetan Lal",
    "designation": "Managing Director",
    "image": "/images/Chetan-Lal-edit.jpg",
    "about": "This is just test",
    "child": [
        {
            "key": "c1",
            "name": "Shagufta Merchant",
            "designation": "VP-Digital Operations & HR",
            "image": "/Images/Shagufta-Merchant-edit - Copy.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test2",
            "child": [
                {
                    "key": "gc1",
                    "name": "Manjiri Nadkarni",
                    "designation": "Manager - NA Media Ops",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "key": "ggc1",
                            "name": "Anurag Bhagrav",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - Media Ops",
                            "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ggc2",
                            "name": "Janhavi Chaudhari",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - Media Ops",
                            "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ggc3",
                            "name": "Anurag Shetty",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - Media Ops",
                            "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc2",
                    "name": "Shailendra More",
                    "designation": "Manager - NA Media Ops",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "key": "ggc1",
                            "name": "AjayKumar Padhy",
                            "designation": "Team Leader - SEO & Auto",
                            "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ggc2",
                            "name": "Jignesh Shah",
                            "designation": "Asist. Manager",
                            "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc3",
                    "name": "Vaishakhi Phadke",
                    "designation": "Asst. Manager - NA Media Ops",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "key": "ggc1",
                            "name": "Hassel Rathod",
                            "designation": "Team Manger - National",
                            "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                            "about": "This is just test2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc4",
                    "name": "Mitesh More",
                    "designation": "Training Team Manager",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc5",
                    "name": "Shrutika Jadhav",
                    "designation": "Manager - HR",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "gc6",
                    "name": "Tejinder Ossan",
                    "designation": "Manager - Facility",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "c2",
            "name": "Bhavesh Chauhan",
            "designation": "VP-Marketing Operations & IT",
            "image": "/Images/Bhavesh-Chauhan-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test3",
            "child": [
                {
                    "key": "gc7",
                    "name": "Justie Lewis",
                    "designation": "Manager - Media Ops",
                    "image": "/Images/placeholder.jpg",
                    "about": "This is just test3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "c3",
            "name": "Sanket Naik",
            "designation": "VP-Marketing Operations & Graphics",
            "image": "/Images/Sanket-Naik-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test4"
        },
        {
            "key": "c4",
            "name": "Ankanksha Narula",
            "designation": "Sr. Manager - Finance",
            "image": "/Images/Akansha-Narula-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test5"
        },
        {
            "key": "c5",
            "name": "Diju Kurup",
            "designation": "Manager - Marketing Operations",
            "image": "/Images/Diju-Kurup-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test6"
        },
        {
            "key": "c6",
            "name": "Arya Andrade",
            "designation": "Manager - Facility",
            "image": "/Images/Arya-Andrade-edit.jpg",
            "about": "This is just test7"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Will you please post the relevant code here, too?

Answer (score 0):

set your parent's flex-box align items to start...this will prevent items going down with the dropdown

```
<div
   style={{
     display: "flex",
     justifyContent: "center",
     alignItems: "start"
    }}
 >
...
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Please check my live code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-haze-xw2qk3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried with your code

Comment: I updated your code in my sandbox.

Comment: so the alignment issue is fixed i guess

Comment: Not yet. Still the same issue. Additionally, it is not responsive.

Comment: for responsiveness you can use `flex-wrap: wrap` to your parent component, increase the gap

Comment: Thanks. However, if you check my code, when i click any of the 2nd layer elements, it breaks the alignment of the second layer and the child doesn't display in the window frame. can you please try using my sandbox code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252481/discussion-between-sameer-and-buzz).

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the fact that the child nodes are rendered within the parent's containing div; When you expand a node with more than one child, it makes the parent's container wider.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| parent                          | parent | parent |
| child  | child  | child | child |        |        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Two possible fixes:

1. Make the `children` div `position: absolute`, taking it out of the regular layout flow. Here's a [proof of concept fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hopper-gbps78). I don't recommend this; position absolute creates brittle layouts.
2. Render the children outside of the parent div, possibly by moving the rendering responsibility up to the root of the tree.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| parent | parent | parent | parent | parent | parent |
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
| child | child  | child | child |                    |
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
| child | child  | child | child | child |            |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

With either of these approaches your child nodes will no longer be aligned with their parent. If you care about that you'll have to figure out a way to position them to appear properly anchored

Comment: Hi Ray, Making children div position: absolute will resolve the problem but i want parent div in the center. so this approach doesn't help. I tried earlier too with this approach.

Rendering the child outside the parent div will impact the functionality of my toggle mode function which I really don't want.

Comment: You can still center the parent. Why don't you want to modify the toggle functionality?

Comment: The toggle functionality is working fine. If i  make change to children div, it doesn't work. as i said i am new to react, hence, i do not want to change the toggle functionality.

However, I noticed that the parent div is displayed under the child div. i was able to make the parent div in the center but when i click on the parent div, the child displays inline with parent. 

here is gif: https://giphy.com/gifs/gWfmIaHmeRk2vpX4CH

Comment: Without looking my guess is that this is because you're setting position absolute _and setting `top`_. If you don't set `top` it will land vertically where it would've already been. You're doing a ton of unnecessary absolute positioning on everything and that's going to make your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I added my code in sandbox, top and absolute position is necessary to place the element correctly with respect to the parent.  However, it is causing issue( as you said). Can you please let me know what property should I use?

Comment: What i feel is that we need to change the state of the CSS's property to get it fixed.

Comment: not yet. tried multiple things but it did not work

Comment: I tinkered with this a bit. [Here's an updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-raman-bil69u?file=/src/Card.css). It centers the children under the expanded parent now (via the useChildStyle hook) and it uses less absolute positioning. You could set up a [resize observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to keep the children centered when resizing.